# Add Specific Column of Data from CSV to Heroku Table Without Affecting Existing Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, csv, heroku

I have a CSV with a list of user email addresses. I need to add these addresses as new records to my heroku user table without affecting the user rows that are already in there. The CSV is not currently in the same table format as the heroku table, it is simply one column of data.

I have tried a few methods, however they seem to start by removing the data that is currently in the table before importing. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Email list is in same order as records there on heroku? Means first email in csv should match to 1st record in user table and so on ?

Comment: The email addresses are not for the current records. They are to be added as new records in the table. Each email address in my CSV should lead to one new record in my user table. They are in no particular order.

Comment: So simply create a seed file for this. How many column your csv file have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering you have csv with head "email"

Your seed file will look like :

```
require 'csv'

data = CSV.read(Rails.root.to_s + '/public/csvfile', headers: true)
data['email'].each do |email|
  @user = User.new(:email => email)
  User.save(:validate => false)
end
```

Comment: After a few tweaks, this has worked perfectly. Thanks Nitin :)

Comment: It'll be horrifyingly slow for large user counts, though. If you want to do it efficiently, `COPY` the csv into a new table, then do an `UPDATE ... FROM` to do a joined update adding the new field.